# How to count Splendor bonus gems

Tags: splendor

In the game of Splendor when you have a developer card with prestige points on it, is that the number of gems it produces also? Or is it just one gem per card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each card only gives a bonus of one gem. Prestige points are purely points.

For example, on page 3 of the [rulebook](http://www.spacecowboys.fr/img/games/splendor/details/rules/Rules_Splendor_US.pdf), there is an example of a player gaining 4 prestige points and a single blue bonus from a development card.

Answer (score 0):

Yes each card that you "purchased" gives you on extra "permanent" gem. And only one.